# Using ActionListener with JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener

I have just started using JFrame and I have a button that when clicked will perform calculations and output a result and a button that clears all of the users inputs. I know that I need to create two new classes which implement Action Listener. When it comes to creating the classes.

I was wondering if it is better practice to create the classes within my class that creates the JFrame or to make two separate classes and use getters and setters to modify the content of my JFrame class.

Comment: At this stage, it's best to write code that works. Later you can worry about M-V-C'ing your program, but right now, best to concentrate on pure functionality.

Comment: Also, much depends on just what your listeners do. If they're simple few-line listeners, then go via anonymous inner classes. If they interact with complex objects and have states and behaviors, then go with separate stand-alone classes. In between perhaps use private inner classes. Note that you're rarely want to create a class that extends JFrame and you'll never want your GUI classes to implement any listener interfaces.

Comment: Why is it bad to implement listener interfaces?

Comment: It's not bad to implement interfaces as you must do this, but it's bad to have your view classes implement listener interfaces as that would be giving the class too much responsibility.